# Where do you install an SSL?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

If you have web apps and modules on Azure and your domain on Host Gator, where should you install the SSL? It seems logical it would be azure as that's where the data is actually passing.

If Azure, do you need to do anything on Host Gator to recognize the SSL?

Answer (score 1):

You could just follow the steps on the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl), there are detailed description about how to upload SSL certificate and bind it. This is the [part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl#bind-your-ssl-certificate) of binding certificate. Remind check your App Service plan before binding certificate, select any of the non-free tiers.

**Note:** If you have uploaded your certificate but don't see the domain name(s) in the Hostname dropdown, try refreshing the browser page.

About HostGator, if you have mapped domain with this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) and it worked, then you don't need to do other things, just prepare your SSL certificate and check the certificate [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-ssl#requirements-for-your-ssl-certificate).

Hope this could you, if you still have other questions,please let me know.